# Plot with variable limit of integration in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numerical-integration

I have function f(x) and I want to integrate the function from 0 to some point x
in the interval (0,2). I know how to solve the problem in mathematica, however I don't know how to solve this problem in python.

**Mathematica**

```
OM=0.3
OL=0.7
f[x_] := ((1 + x)^3 OM + OL)^(-1/2);
Plot[NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, z2}], {z2, 0, 2}]
```

My code in **python**:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate

y = np.linspace(0, 2, 20)
Om=0.3
Ol=1-Om

def H(x):
    return (Om*(1+x)**3 +Ol)**(-1./2)

#Integral from a single point in the inverval
print quad(H,0,2)
```

How can I do exactly the same in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[integrate.quad(H, 0, t)[0] for t in y]
```

`quad`s inputs are `f, a, b`, here you do integration from `0` to `t` for all `t` in `y`.